# Add Custom Zend Form Element Decorator Via Bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-decorators

I have created a new decorator and have added it to my form using addElementPrefixPath. I intend to use this decorator in other forms but do not want to add it every time. How do I add this decorator via the bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally extend Zend_Form and use that form instead. As below:

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form {
    protected $decorator = ..........;
}
```

That file would go in ./library/My/Form.php. And then in all of my forms they would be:

```
class App_Form_Example extends My_Form {
    ....
}
```

If you haven't used auto loader namespaces before you will need to add this to your application.ini (assuming you start your extended form with "My_"

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_"
```

I hope that helps.  Let me know if I misunderstood your question or I didn't make myself clear :)